# Create a copy to clipboard button in Sidebar using Google's `Apps Script`

Tags: google-apps-script, clipboard, sidebar

Is there a way to create a copy to clipboard button in Sidebar using Google's `Apps Script`?

My current code is the following, but the copy button is not working:

```
function createCalendarEvent() {
  
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput()
      .setTitle("Πληροφορίες για Ημερολόγιο")
      .setContent('<div><p id="item-to-copy">Test</p>' + '\n\n<button onclick='+"copyToClipboard()"+'>Copy</button></div>')
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      ui.showSidebar(html);
}

function copyToClipboard() {
    const str = document.getElementById('item-to-copy').innerText;
    const el = document.createElement('textarea');
    el.value = str;
    el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
    el.style.position = 'absolute';
    el.style.left = '-9999px';
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    el.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
```

document.body.removeChild(el);
}

The second function is javascipt.

Can you help me please?

**Edit**
When I click F12 on the browser, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: copyToClipboard is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (userCodeAppPanel:1)
onclick @ userCodeAppPanel:1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "copy to clipboard"? Could you explain what is the intention of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Modification points:

- From `The second function is javascipt.`, in your script, if `copyToClipboard()` is put to the HTML file of the script editor, in that case, `html` in your script doesn't include the function. By this, such error occurs.
- Or, if `copyToClipboard()` is put to the Google Apps Script file of the script editor, `copyToClipboard()` cannot be run from HTML side. By this, such error occurs.

In order to run `copyToClipboard()`, I would like to propose the following modification.

### Modified script:

#### HTML&Javascript side:

Please copy and paste the following script to the HTML file of the script editor in Google Apps Script project. The filename is `index.html`.

```
<div>
  <p id="item-to-copy">Test</p>
  <button onclick="copyToClipboard()">Copy</button>
</div>
<script>
function copyToClipboard() {
  const str = document.getElementById('item-to-copy').innerText;
  const el = document.createElement('textarea');
  el.value = str;
  el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
  el.style.position = 'absolute';
  el.style.left = '-9999px';
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  el.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(el);
}
</script>
```

#### Google Apps Script side:

Please copy and paste the following script to the Google Apps Script file of the script editor in Google Apps Script project.

```
function createCalendarEvent() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index").setTitle("Πληροφορίες για Ημερολόγιο")
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
  ui.showSidebar(html);
}
```

- When `createCalendarEvent()` is run, the script loads the HTML & Javascript from `index.html` file.

### Note:

- If you want to use `setContent`, you can also use the following scripts.

  - HTML&Javascript side:

    ```
      <script>
      function copyToClipboard() {
        const str = document.getElementById('item-to-copy').innerText;
        const el = document.createElement('textarea');
        el.value = str;
        el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
        el.style.position = 'absolute';
        el.style.left = '-9999px';
        document.body.appendChild(el);
        el.select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
        document.body.removeChild(el);
      }
      </script>
    ```
  - Google Apps Script side:

    ```
      function createCalendarEvent() {
        var javascript = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index").getContent();
        var htmlData = `<div><p id="item-to-copy">Test</p><button onclick="copyToClipboard()">Copy</button></div>${javascript}`;
        var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput()
        .setTitle("Πληροφορίες για Ημερολόγιο")
        .setContent(htmlData)
        var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
        ui.showSidebar(html);
      }
    ```

### References:

- [Class HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service)
- [HTML Service: Create and Serve HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html)

Comment: This is a great answer. Can it be modified to simply copy into the clipboard the contents of the active cell in a Google Sheet? I just want a button that copies the contents of the current cell so I can paste it into another app.

Comment: @nollaf126 About your question of `Can it be modified to simply copy into the clipboard the contents of the active cell in a Google Sheet? I just want a button that copies the contents of the current cell so I can paste it into another app.`, can you post it as a new question? Because this is not your question. By posting it as a new question, it will help users think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Of course! Cooperation is the name of the game. I'll get right on it. Thanks, @Tanaike.

Comment: I posted the new question and added detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76239069/google-sheets-google-scripts-button-to-copy-the-contents-of-active-cell-to-the-a

Comment: @nollaf126 Thank you for your response. I believe that it will help users think of a solution.